# Iterating through Array of Objects to fill input fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am currently working on a workaround for Google Forms which will be able to store all inputs in cookies so a user can proceed the survey at a different time.
At the moment I am able to store all questions (a Question is a object that contains: id of the surrounding div, required, userinput in a cookie by using `JSON.stringify()`. I am also able to read and parse the cookie which gets me an array of all question objects.

Now I want to fill all fields or check all radio buttons which have a value. 
My problem is, that the inner for loop does only 2 iterations but it should do 18. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

```
function restoreInputs() {
    // number of stored cookies
    var countCookies = 27;
    console.log(countCookies);
    // iterate through all cookies
    for (var i = 1; i < countCookies + 1; i++) {
        var cookiename = "answer" + i;
        // get content of cookie (is array of objects)
        var answer = checkCookie(cookiename);
        // iterate through content      
        for (var j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
            // get value of object
            var val = answer[j].value;
            // get the input field (textarea or radio button)
            var x = document.getElementById(answer[j].n).getElementsByTagName('input');
            // if input is radio, then check the one at position stored in value of object
            if (x[j].type === "radio") {
                x[val].checked = true;
                // if textarea set its value to the one stored in object value
            } else {
                x[j].value = val;
            }
            console.log("j: " + j);
        }

    }
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Why should it do 18 instead of 2?  The code example you have shown gives us no information as to what happens in `checkCookie()` to where someone could understand why `answer` has a `length` of 2.  Have you tried doing `console.log(answer)` to see what value you are getting and compared that against what you expect?

Comment: What is the contents of var answer = checkCookie(cookiename)? My first guess is the length is not 18 but would need to see the data to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that I forgot a for loop, since `var x = document.getElementById(answer[j].n).getElementsByTagName('input');` may return more than one element. So here is the solution:

```
function restoreInputs() {
// number of stored cookies
var countCookies = 27;
console.log(countCookies);
// iterate through all cookies
for (var i = 1; i < countCookies + 1; i++) {
    var cookiename = "answer" + i;
    // get content of cookie (is array of objects)
    var answer = checkCookie(cookiename);
    // iterate through content      
    for (var j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
        // get value of object
        var val = answer[j].value;
        // get the input field (textarea or radio button)
        var x = document.getElementById(answer[j].n).getElementsByTagName('input');
        // if input is radio, then check the one at position stored in value of object
        for (var k = 0; k < x.length; k++) {

            if (x[k].type === "radio") {

                x[val].checked = true;
                // if textarea set its value to the one stored in object value
            } else {
                x[k].value = val;
            }
        }
        console.log("j: " + j);
    }
}
console.log(i);
```

}

Comment: It could be that your checkCookie returns undefined. Debug your code with a breakpoint on the inner loop.

An important point you should have in mind is Javascript variables are function-scoped and not block-scoped.

Comment: @ctarabusi Very usfull comment, thanks! I'm using now `if (Object.prototype.toString.call( answer ) === '[object Array]' )` to check if answer is an array before I loop through it. So it will not crash if answer is undefined.